# Blazor CheckBox when to init "checked"

Tags: css, blazor

I'm trying to navigate in a input radio cardtab with @cheked...

Like

```
<input name="nav" type="radio" class="nav home-radio" id="box" checked="@ChkBox" />

im trying it that way:

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CreateBoxNav(1);
}
public void CreateBoxNav(int _checked)
    {


        if (_checked == 1)
        {
            ChkBox = "checked";
            ChkItm = "";
            ChkClc = "";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        ...

}
```

Where should I need to init ChkBox to have the first tab open?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just data bind to an [InputCheckbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputcheckbox?view=aspnetcore-5.0) or handle the @onchange event?

Comment: 1 cardtab is part of an edit few i want to aproach from a list fiew...like ---firstname--lastname--phone-[edit] [delete]...on click the edit btn change to edit tab with item values

Answer (score 0):

Simple way the Fastest way:
ive made a navlable for the method, like:

<label class="nav cardtablabel" for="ItemView" @onclick="@(e=>SelectItem(x))">

Edit

Comment: If your need is to have clickable text that does something, I would use an anchor or button.